# Show a random link when my web page has been refreshed

Tags: php

I am trying to use the code bellow to echo a random url at a new web page refresh but i can't make it work

```
<?php
$url=array(
'http://www.google.com',
'http://www.in.gr',
'http://www.yahoo.gr'
);
$random=rand(1,count($url));
echo $url[$random];
?>
```

Thank you all!

Comment: what exactly is the problem?

Comment: What do you mean there is nothing wrong with this code ???

Comment: @user2180613 there **is** one thing wrong. See all the answers!

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
$random=rand(1,count($url));
```

With

```
$random = mt_rand(0, count($url) - 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried this, but it should work... I hope..

```
<?php
$url=array(
'http://www.google.com',
'http://www.in.gr',
'http://www.yahoo.gr'
);

$rand =  rand(0, 2);

echo $url[$rand];
```

Comment: This is no different than what she has.

Comment: @Brad What do you mean? It works or I must have missed the question

Answer (score 0):

Array index starts from 0 and end up with length-1. 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php
First value is minimum value. Which is 0. 
Second value is max value which is last index of array.

```
<?php
$url=array(
'http://www.google.com',
'http://www.in.gr',
'http://www.yahoo.gr'
);
$random=rand(0,count($url));
echo $url[$random];
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change to:

```
$random=rand(0, count($url)-1);
```

The problem with your code is you set the minimum as 1 and the max as the total number of URLs. Arrays are zero based, so you need 0 as the minimum, and you need `count($url)-1` as the maximum. In this case you have 3 URLs, but the third URL is in `$url[2]` not `$url[3]`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php
  $url = array(
    'http://www.google.com',
    'http://www.in.gr',
    'http://www.yahoo.gr'
  );
  $random = array_rand($input);
  echo $url[$random];
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The first key of the array would be 0. So change the rand function to this:

```
rand( 0,count($url) - 1 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all change this:

```
$random=rand(1,count($url));
```

to

```
$random=rand(0,count($url) - 1);
```

arrays starting index is 0